# html chat window layout, how can i make the chatview use 100% percent of the page - the size of the lineedit

Tags: css, html

i'm trying to create a html5 chat client, where i have a layout with the
big chatwindow on the top and a small lineedit at the bottom:

```
+-------------------+
|                   |
|                   |
|                   |
|                   |
+-------------------+
|                   |
+-------------------+
```

How can i create a layout that always adopts to the window size?
I tried lots of thing but i either get a 100% size chatwindow, or two boxes but not high 
enough.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Chat Example</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.17/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="client.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
html {
    overflow: hidden;
}

body {
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: gray;
}

#tabs{
    margin:0;
    padding-top:4em;
    padding-left:12em;
    padding-bottom:3em;
    background: red;
}

#container{
    margin-left:5px;
    margin-right:5px;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    margin-top:0px;
    min-height:10em;
    position: relative;
    background: green;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="tabs">
    <p>Bar</p>
    </div>
    <div id="container" class="ui.widget">
    <p>Foo</p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`position:absolute;`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-positioning/#absolute-positioning). [JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VSNCA/embedded/result/). This won't work in [IE&le6;](http://quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#t28), but works fine in IE≥7 and other browsers (FF, Opera, Chrome).

```
<div id="chatwindow">
 <div id="messagewindow">
  <!-- messages -->
 </div>
 <div id="inputcontainer"><p>Your message</p></div>
</div>
```

```css
#chatwindow{
    position:relative;
    height:400px; /* if you wish to use all of your space, use
    position:absolute; top:0;left:0;right:0;bottom:0;
    or drop the chatdwindow div */
}
#messagewindow, #inputcontainer{
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    border:1px solid #000;
}
#messagewindow{   
    overflow:auto;
    top:0;
    bottom:3em;
}
#inputcontainer{
    display:block;
    bottom:0;
    height:1em;
    padding:.5em;
    margin-top:1em;
}

#inputcontainer > p{
    margin:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="top">
        </div>
        <div id="bottom">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
html {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#top {
    height: 100%;
    border:1px solid black;
}
#bottom {
    height: 100px;
    margin-top: -100px;
    border:1px solid black;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/29hA9/2/

Comment: Hey thx for answering, this almost shows me what i need, except that i have to scroll down to see the bottom part. At least in chrome and firefox, i didn't try other browsers.

Comment: Yes you 're right, now should work, I added the margin-bottom.

Comment: Using a negative `margin` is often not recommended. See what happens if you have too much text: http://jsfiddle.net/29hA9/3/

Comment: @Zeta any idea how one can do that without the overflow?

Comment: even overflow:auto; can not fix the behaviour